# How to boost score of Solr search results based on criteria?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lucene, solr, websolr

Background:

1 - I'm using WebSolr for this search.
2 - I have two fields stored in websolr - name and id.

I want to search for these entries based on name AND boost the search score based on this criteria:

```
if id in [x1,x2..xN] then +2
if id in [y1,y2..yN] then +1
else +0
```

From my research, the answer lies in the following
- Function query, or
- DisMaxQParser

I have looked at the documentation but IMO its not very comprehensive.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use boosts. Try a query like

```
name:searchString AND ( id:[x1 TO xN] ^2 OR id:[y1 TO yN]^1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to hkn's approach, you could also use [DisMax query parser](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin) boost queries:

```
q=queryString
&defType=dismax
&qf=…
&bq=id:[x1+TO+xN]^3
&bq=id:[y1+TO+yN]^2
```

(Untested, but should convey the idea.)